# How do I plot data vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My data is reading horizontally right now but I want my data to read vertically (e.g. I have an 'x' column with data below it and likewise for 'y' so I can plot with vertical data instead of my picture with horizontal data.

[image: plot]

Comment: I have a chart, went to Help, Change Rows to Columns.  It was prepared to do this. Try Help as I have outlined

Comment: Switch the data?

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you have "x" on the left and "y" on the right.

If you switch these it will invert the graph.

Hope this helps.